# How to append arrays to existing json array and write to file in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have a `example.json` file.

```
{
  "tc" :
  [
    {"name" : "tc_001"},
    {"name" : "tc_002"},
    {"name" : "tc_003"},
    {"name" : "tc_004"},
    {"name" : "tc_005"}
  ]
}
```

In here I need to add another array to the `tc[0]th` index. In `Node JS` I tried this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('example.json', 'utf8'));
var arr1 = {bc :[{name:'bc_001'}]}
var arr2 = {bc :[{name:'bc_002'}]}
obj.tc[0] = arr1;
obj.tc[0] = arr2;
```

But when printing that `obj`, `obj.tc[0]` has replaced by value of `arr2`.
The final result I want to achieve is:

```
{
  "tc" :
  [
    {
       "name" : "tc_001"
       "bc" :
       [
            {"name" = "bc_001"},
            {"name" = "bc_002"}
       ]
    },
    {"name" : "tc_002"},
    {"name" : "tc_003"},
    {"name" : "tc_004"},
    {"name" : "tc_005"}
  ]
}
```

I also want to write this back to the same `json` file.
I'm trying to achieve here a file containing number of `tc`s with unique names. Furthermore one `tc` can have multiple `bc`s, and `bc` has a name attribute.

I also accept suggestion on a better `json` structure to support this concept.

Comment: what do you mean by better object structure? it depends on the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

A solution for more than one item to add to the object.

It uses an object `o` where the new values should go and a value object `v` with the keys and the items to assign.

Inside it iterates over the keys and build a new array if not already there. Then all values are pushed to the array.

```js
function add(o, v) {
    Object.keys(v).forEach(k => {
        o[k] = o[k] || [];
        v[k].forEach(a => o[k].push(a));
    });
}

var obj = { "tc": [{ "name": "tc_001" }, { "name": "tc_002" }, { "name": "tc_003" }, { "name": "tc_004" }, { "name": "tc_005" }] };

add(obj.tc[0], { bc: [{ name: 'bc_001' }] });
add(obj.tc[0], { bc: [{ name: 'bc_002' }] });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I'm sorry i edited the question. i want to add two `bc`s to `tc` one. Could you please edit the answer

Comment: It's working but hard to understand `function add(o, v)`. Could you please simplify that if it's possible.